# TortoiseSVN Update Head from Revision

Tags: tortoisesvn, revision

I am new to tortoiseSVN - What is the best way to update the head from a revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your working copy, do a [backmerge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) to a revision before the start of the work on the "long feature" and then commit.

Comment: Is that a simple "update to revision" in tortoise Svn? If yes, what happens to the future revisions that are there - are they being deleted from the repository?

Comment: If I remember well, when you select Merge from Tortoise there is a checkbox called "Reverse merge" to tell that you are backmerging (see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html#tsvn-dug-merge-range). Nothing is deleted from the repository of course, you just add a new revision which contains your codebase without the "long feature" code.

Comment: But wont that change my current revision (the one without the long feature) with the changes from future revisions?

Comment: I just tried it and it changed my code from the "long feature" with the one from the revision. I would like to avoid that. Is there a way?

Comment: Let's say you started the long feature in revision 100 and that you branched the long feature out in revision 110, that is now the HEAD. You checkout a working copy from the trunk (at revision 110), backmerge it with revision 99 and commit: you have now revision 111 without the long feature code. The code in the branch with the long feature is not affected.

Comment: You should probably mark Davide's answer as accepted. This way he'll receive the reputation and it'll be clearer what the question was.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your working folder with the latest (HEAD) revision from the repository then right click on the Folder and select 'SVN update'.

If you want to commit the changes you made locally to the repository, so that the HEAD revision will incorporate your changes then right click on the Folder and select 'SVN commit'.

Comment: Just on the off chance, what if the OP means 'update' in a non-SVN terminology fashion? How does he update local changes to the repository. By doing an Add (if new content) followed by a Commit. ;-)

Comment: Only saying that because if OP is aware of 'SVN update', why ask the question?

Comment: Manu, thats not what I mean. I had a feature that I was working on in the head of the repository. Now this feature takes longer then expected. Now I need to add another small feature to the project, which doesn't effect the "long feature". Now I created a branch for the "long feature" and updated the working directory from a revision which was before I started to work on the "long feature". Now I want this revision to be the head.